# Need some help in generating the group element by generator using GAP system

Tags: group-theory, gap

I am new to GAP system. I would like to generate group using presentation of group. For example, dihedral group D_{2n} with generator . Can anyone familiar with GAP system help me out with this?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to construct a group from a presentation.

```
n := 4;;
F := FreeGroup(2);         # Free group of rank two
a := F.1;; b := F.2;;      # Name generators
R := [a^2, b^2, (a*b)^n];; # Relations for D_2n
G := F/R;;

StructureDescription(G);   # This should yield "D8"
```

You may also want names for the generators to play with.

```
a := G.1;; b := G.2;;      # Rename
List([a, b, a*b], Order);  # This should yield [2, 2, 4]
```

---

**Added**. Here is another—more clean—way to do the same, which I learned from Hulpke's talk. (See https://www.icts.res.in/program/GTACM16/talks for his videos and slides.)

```
F := FreeGroup("a", "b");
R := ParseRelators(F, "a2, b2, (ab)4");
G := F/R;
IsomorphismGroups(G, DihedralGroup(8)) <> fail;
AssignGeneratorVariables(G);
List([a, b, a*b], Order);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. May I know is there any built in function to multiply two group (either subset, subgroup) together in the following manner: Eg : A=(a_1,a_2), B=(b_1,b_2), A*B= (a_1*b_1, a_1*b_2, a_2*b_1, a_2*b_2)? I read through the GAP manual and other sources about the product of subgroup. What I found out doesnt suit my case. One of the built in function is Direct Product (not suitable for this case). One of the way I can think of is to transform the Group into the Ring, then perform the multiplication? Is it possible to do so? Or we have other better choice for this case?Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by A=(a_1,a_2). Also, it sounds like another question, not related to the original one.